# Impersonation in SQL Server Views?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to create views with impersonation, similar to `"execute as"` in stored procedures?

I would like to create some views in a separate schema. Some users should get `SELECT` and `UPDATE` access to these views, so that they are  able to change the underlying tables, but without having  direct update access to the table.

Is that possible with a view ?

Comment: Yes this is possible (through ownership chaining). What would you hope to get out of it though? Why is it easier to manage permissions on the view than an underlying table?

Comment: Well the view selects only a couple of rows, and the user can then only uodate these rows. This is different to a table. Furthermore, I think it's generally better to not touch tables directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. EXECUTE AS is mainly used with SP's, but you can use them a bit more widely. [From TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

> In SQL Server you can define the execution context of the following
>   user-defined modules: functions (except inline table-valued
>   functions), procedures, queues, and triggers.
>
> ...
>
> Functions (except inline table-valued functions), Stored Procedures,
>   and DML Triggers { EXEC | EXECUTE } AS { CALLER | SELF | OWNER |
>   'user_name' }
>
> DDL Triggers with Database Scope { EXEC | EXECUTE } AS { CALLER | SELF
>   | 'user_name' }
>
> DDL Triggers with Server Scope and logon triggers { EXEC | EXECUTE }
>   AS { CALLER | SELF | 'login_name' }
>
> Queues { EXEC | EXECUTE } AS { SELF | OWNER | 'user_name' }

However, you have some options here:

- create GET-SP's that return your data and UPDATE-SP's that upate your data (I use XML input for this instead of table-variables)
- use views created by your 'impersonated' user, and play with permission inheritance breaking using DENY/GRANT, like GRANT VIEW DEFINITION

Comment: Well, it seems that it IS possible, but under the consideration of ownership chaining. I will post an answer later here.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough - creating views with impersonation is not possible, but breaking ownership chain by granting securable permission to someone, like e.g. view definition permission on object may be a way to go here. There is a reference to it in my answer.