# How to create a database role on SQL server where a user in that role can only select from one view, and not from the tables used in the view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, roles

I want to create a role where users can only see and select from 1 single view, and they can not select from the tables used in a view.

I have this code so far:

```
use enterprise_product_prod
go
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(3000)
DECLARE @RoleName NVARCHAR(100) = 'only_view_test2';
DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(100) = 'Ignite';
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(100) = 'GAN_Amounts';
DECLARE GrantExec_Cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
for
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON [' + @Schema  + '].[' + 
                             @Name  + '] TO [' + @RoleName + ']; ' AS SQLstatement
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
OPEN GrantExec_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM GrantExec_Cursor INTO @SQL

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN --Grant Permissions
    EXEC(@SQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM GrantExec_Cursor INTO @SQL
END --Grant Permissions

CLOSE GrantExec_Cursor
DEALLOCATE GrantExec_Cursor
GO
```

It works fine, if I add a test user to this role, I can only see the view "Ignite.Gan_amounts", but when I want to run a simple select on this view, I get the following error:

The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Tbl_FX', database 'ENTERPRISE_PRODUCT_PROD', schema 'SCLR'.

Tbl_FX is one of the tables used in the view.

How can I reach that the users in this role can only see and select from this view without having this error? I do not want them to be able to select from the original tables.

Comment: See if the third solution here works for you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368414/grant-select-on-a-view-not-base-table-when-base-table-is-in-a-different-database  The issue isn't that you can't restrict read to just the view, it's that you can't do that with a view *across schemas* without running into issues.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a table function instead of a view or put the view on the table function. That table function should then use a `EXECUTE AS OWNER` clause in order to be able to grant the execute rights on that function alone.

Here's a basic [TVF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with execute as owner:

```
create function testTVF() returns @testTable table (a int)
with execute as owner as
begin
  insert into @testTable select 1 a union all select 2 a;
  return;
end;
go
```

I tried to create an inline TVF but that failed with `An invalid option was specified for the statement "CREATE/ALTER FUNCTION"`

You cannot do that with the view alone. See [Impersonation in SQL Server Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203700/impersonation-in-sql-server-views).